# awk - table of distinct values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

With this "|" delimited file: dummy.dat

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2|1|-28.03720000
9|2
10
jgn352|1|-28.03720000
9|2|fdjkjhn422-405
0000543210|gfdjk39
```

For example the value "-28.03720000" in the latitude field appears twice, then in the output it will appear once but have at the end of it(2). Another example, the value "2" appeared once in the sid field but twice in the storeno field - so for output it will have one entry under the sid field (with "(1)" at the end) and one entry under the storeno field (with "(2)" at the end).

Desired result:

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
9(2)|1(2)|-28.03720000(2)
0000543210(1)|2(2)|fdjkjhn422-405(1)
10(1)|gfdjk39(1)    
2(1)
jgn352(1)
```

Another example of acceptable desired result (given the same input file):

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
9(2)|2(2)|-28.03720000(2)
jgn352(1)|1(2)|fdjkjhn422-405(1)
10(1)|gfdjk39(1)    
0000543210(1)
2(1)
```

What is the generic solution to produce such output as above? I am open to awk, bash, perl.etc
It is the distinct values of each field (with the count of the occurences of that value in "()" and then ordered desc by those count of occurrences):

Have found these 2 code snippets that get the general idea but just in a different output format:

```
Script 1:
awk -F"|" ' {
                for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                {
                        count[i " " $(i)]++;    # count by field number and field value
                        uniq[$(i)] = 1;         # save a list of unique strings
                }
                if( NF > fields )
                        fields = NF;            # in case a variable number in file; capture max
        }
        END {
                for( i = 1; i <= fields; i++ )
                {
                        printf( "field %d\n", i );
                        for( x in uniq )
                                if( count[i " " x] )
                                        printf( "%s (%d)\n", x, count[i " " x] );  # print by field and value
                        printf( "\n" );
                }
        } ' dummy.dat

Script 2:
awk -F"|" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i FS $i]++} END {for (i in a) print i,"(",a[i],")" |"sort -n" } ' dummy.dat
```

Comment: Can you please explain the relationship between the input and desired output? It is not very intuitive

Comment: very confusing format - what determines which row an entry shows up in?

Comment: @SiegeX - The desired output will have for each field in the input: the distinct values for that field (and the number of times that value appeared in the field). kfmfe04 - It does not matter which row an entry in the desired output appears. You can think of the output as the distinct values of each field just stuck together into one file.

Comment: @toop What determines what goes on the same row in the output? For example, why is 9,1,-28.03720000 and longitude on the same row but others not?

Comment: The desired output looks crazy!! :)

Comment: @SiegeX - I fixed up the desired output (it was not meant to have a fieldname under a fieldname). It is not important what goes on the same row (this can be random). It is just stitching together the distinct values of each column (ordered in desc order by number of times the value appears under the field).

Comment: @JaypalSingh cheers for the `nawk` suggestion

Comment: I looked at this cheat sheet [here](http://www.catonmat.net/download/awk.cheat.sheet.pdf) and thought may be that could cause issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '

FNR==NR{
  if(FNR>1)
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      a[$i,i]++
  next
}
FNR==1{print}
FNR>1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
    if(b[$j,j]++)
      printf("|")
    else
      printf("%s(%s)|",$j,a[$j,j])
  print ""
}' ./dummy.dat ./dummy.dat | sed 's/|*$//'
```

#### Output

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2(1)|1(2)|-28.03720000(2)
9(2)|2(2)
10(1)
jgn352(1)
||fdjkjhn422-405(1)
0000543210(1)|gfdjk39(1)
```

***Note:*** <strike>Getting rid of the trailing `|` is going to take some extra work. Hopefully this will suffice.</strike>
I just passed the final output to `sed 's/|*$//'`

Comment: Given the wicked desired output, this is sight for sore eyes!! +1

Comment: This gives me:
awk: syntax error near line 4...10..11
awk: illegal statement near line 4...10..11

Comment: @toop Perhaps FNR is a `gawk`ism. [HERE](http://ideone.com/y5r7G) is an example of it working with `gawk`. Note I had to use process substitution for the input because ideone doesn't allow you to create files.

Comment: @loop try using `nawk`, I am not sure if solaris `awk` has support for `FNR` built-in variable.

Comment: @SiegeX - Appears to have a bug because fdjkjhn422-405(1) is not in the sid column.

Comment: @toop as written that is desired behavior. When I process the file a second time I go line by line and if a certain field has already been printed I skip it. The reason why `fdjkjhn422-405(1)` is on it's own line is because the `9` and `2` before it have already been printed. Are you expecting two blank `||` before it?

Comment: @SiegeX - Yeah two || before it is ok, or otherwise added onto another line like "9(2)|2(2)|fdjkjhn422-405(1)"

Comment: Awesome, I get output by using nawk. Is there a way that it can also order descending by number of occurrences? ie in the sid column having 9(2) at the top

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file lets say `filename` and then may be do this `head -n 1 filename && sort -k3 -t"(" -nr <(tail +2 filename)`